ubuntu stable enough for a working desktop?
I've been trying to convert from Windows to a stable Linux distro and the process has not been smooth or enjoyable.  Crashes, system behavior does not seem to match descriptions of same.
Machine is a Lenovo T530 laptop with various hardware checks run and memory filled out.  A common experience with Ubuntu--over years and different machines--is display going dark making machine useless.
Starting over: 16.04 from CD in back of a Ubuntu book, followed by upgrade to 18.04.6 LTS.  This seems to go smoothly enough, but package upgrades usually end with ("AMD64") but, the machine is Intel NLTSot AMD.  Is there a way to fix this?  Can I expect the system to work thinking it's AMD?  (Previously, I did an further upgrade to 24.04.1 and this broke the system with a dark screen.)
Any guidance would be appreciated! Would prefer not to revert to Windows unless necessary to get work done.....

AMD64 refers to the 64 bit architecture invented by AMD and used by both Intel and AMD CPUs. There is nothing for you to fix. I don't see a question that is answerable. I have Ubuntu desktop working on 2 laptops, 1 desktop, and 1 Raspberry Pi. The last 2 runs 24/7 without any of the problems you mention.

See this Q&A for more on AMD64.

No-one is using Intel's IA64 architecture that was introduced by Intel to replace x86 (32-bit), as it was not backward compatible, and it died out a few years after introduction. AMD created the amd64 which was backward compatible, and Intel now license it (though AMD still have to license x86 compatibility so payments are both ways & complex), with intel preferring to call it x86_64 rather than advertize AMD in its name. Microsoft too call x86_64 by amd64 if you look at their technical docs.
